# UI - Show textbox as Dropdown(just look and feel)

Tags: html, css

Am having Jquery AutoComplete textbox and we got a requirement to show that as a DropDown(Just look and feel).I came up with some css as below

```
background-image: url("DropDownIcon.png");
background-position: right center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

[image: Screenshot]

If you notice the first Textbox if there is a long text it is overlapping with icon

What are the other option i can implement to make look and feel good without text overlapping the icon or any other suggestions are welcome

i just to have the look and feel and i dont want to use dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `padding-right:12px;` It should work. try this:

```
background-image: url("DropDownIcon.png");
background-position: right center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-right:12px;
```

Updated: check it out
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ueygt4h2/)

Comment: Exactly i tried it before posting which IE8 didnt respond :( . Share fiddle if working fr u

Comment: @Peru You should make a fiddle in my opinion.

Comment: @Peru No...it is working on IE8, I just checked it out.

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt but not fr me. I tried creating Fiddle but am not able upload image to any site to map to fiddle as my proxy is blocking :(

Comment: @Peru OK, I am trying to post mine to jsfiddle. wait.

Comment: @Peru Posted a jsfiddle link, see if that helps

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt Thanks for the link but there is issue in IE8 check result page http://jsfiddle.net/ueygt4h2/embedded/result/  try some long text .